# Roots of unity and coordinates of points in abelian varieties

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

We consider an abelian variety $A$ defined over the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$.  For a torsion point $P\in A(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$, consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(P)$ obtained by adjoining to $\mathbb{Q}$ the coordinates of the point $P$.

For a prime $p$, let $\mu_p$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity and $P$ a $p$-torsion point of $A$.

Is it true that if $\mu_p\notin \mathbb{Q}(P)$, then $\mu_p\notin \mathbb{Q}(nP)$, for $n=1,\dots,p-1$?

If not, how can we characterize this fact?

Answers and comments are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $A$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, meaning that the multiplication map and the coordinates of the group identity are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, then for every pair of closed points $P$ and $R$ of $A$, the compositum $\mathbb{Q}(P,R)$ of $\mathbb{Q}(P)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(R)$ admits a natural field extension $\mathbb{Q}(P+R)\to \mathbb{Q}(P,R)$.  In particular, $\mathbb{Q}(nP)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(P)$.  So if some element $\zeta_p$ is not contained in $\mathbb{Q}(P)$, then it is also not contained in $\mathbb{Q}(nP)$.

Comment: Whence $\mathbb{Q}( P)=\mathbb{Q}( nP)$.